# Let $\mathcal{J}(a,b,c) =\{(x,y) \mid a<x<b, y=c \}.$ Show that the sets $\mathcal{J}(a,b,c)$ form a basis for topology on $\Bbb R^2$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\mathcal{J}(a,b,c) =\{(x,y) \mid a<x<b, y=c \}.$ Where $a,b,c \in \Bbb R$.  Show that the sets $\mathcal{J}(a,b,c)$ form a basis for some topology on $\Bbb R^2$.

In order to show this I need to show that the sets $\mathcal{J}(a,b,c)$ form a cover for $\Bbb R^2$ and that if $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$, then $B_1 \cap B_2 = \emptyset$ or that $B_1 \cap B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$?

It somewhat clear that the sets $\mathcal{J}(a,b,c)$ are a cover for $\Bbb R^2$ however I'm  not sure how to show this rigorously, I haven't learned to use covers like that. The sets $\mathcal{J}(a,b,c)$ looks like

[image]

but from here it seems that there is now way to find two sets say $\mathcal{J}(a,b,c)_1$ and $\mathcal{J}(a,b,c)_2$ for which $\mathcal{J}(a,b,c)_1 \cap \mathcal{J}(a,b,c)_2 = \emptyset$? No matter what $a,b,c$ I choose the lines horizontal lines will intersect the vertical strips?

Comment: your set $I(a,b,c)$ is the green segment inside the red band.

Comment: @TitoEliatron I often go to edit the original question to find out what the MathJax commands are for the symbols involved :).

Comment: @Alan easier way: right click over the formula and click on "Show Math as---->teX Commands"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show they cover the space you just have to show that every ordered pair exists in at least one of them.  So let $(x,y)$ be an arbitrary pair.   Then $(x,y)\in \mathcal{J}(x-1,x+1,y)$

Then you just need that every pairwise intersection is either in the set or empty. So take $\mathcal{J}(a,b,c)$ and $\mathcal{J}(d,e,f)$.  First note that if $c\neq f$,  then they are disjoint.   Then note that if $a\geq e
$ they are also disjoint as the line segment $(a,b)$ is to the right of $(d,e)$.   Likewise,  $(a,b)$ is to the left of $(d,e)$ if $b\leq d$.  Otherwise there is an overlap of the two segments,  and the intersection will just be $\mathcal{J}(\max \{a,d\},\min \{b,e\},c) $

Comment: Do you mean if $a \ge e$, then the sets are disjoint? If $a \ge d$, then part of $(a,b)$ could still be in $(d,e)$, when $a \le e$?

Comment: Ahh,  yes.  Correcting.